# Recognize floating point from input with nom

Tags: rust, parser-combinators

I'm trying to use [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom) to parse a text based protocol. This protocol can have floating point values in it of the form:

```
[-]digit+[.digit+]
```

Examples of which are:

- -10.0
- 10.0
- 10

The nom parser I've built to recognize this is... not pretty. It also doesn't quite typecheck. What I've got so far:

```
named!(float_prs <&[u8], f64>,
       alt!(
           take_while!(nom::is_digit) => {|x| FromStr::from_str(std::str::from_utf8(x).unwrap()).unwrap()} |
           recognize!(chain!(
               take_while!(nom::is_digit) ~
                   tag!(".") ~
                   take_while!(nom::is_digit),
               || {})
           ) => {|x: &[u8]| FromStr::from_str(std::str::from_utf8(x).unwrap()).unwrap() }
       )
);
```

The first alternative parser recognizes `digit+`, the second is an attempt to recognize `digit+.digit+` but

```
<nom macros>:5:38: 5:62 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations or generic parameter binding required [E0282]
<nom macros>:5 let index = ( $ i ) . offset ( i ) ; $ crate:: IResult:: Done (
```

Recognizing `-digit` etc is not addressed in the above. There's a significant amount of duplication and the intent is very much obscured. Is there a better way to parse `[-]digit+[.digit+]` that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nom 2.1 now has float parser helper functions; you should no longer need to do this manually:

- [`float`](http://rust.unhandledexpression.com/nom/fn.float.html)
- [`float_s`](http://rust.unhandledexpression.com/nom/fn.float_s.html)
- [`double`](http://rust.unhandledexpression.com/nom/fn.double.html)
- [`double_s`](http://rust.unhandledexpression.com/nom/fn.double_s.html)

This was [added on Jan 27th](https://github.com/Geal/nom/commit/3196f1a74a8d638f99f1396b8c99215f3f02d49b).

Comment: Could you provide an example usage, please? The documentation doesn't have any examples and I can't wrap my head around the intended usage (I tried doing something like `named!(foo, alt!(double => {...}, ...)` which fails on a simple string like `foo(b"123")`

Comment: `float` does not seem to work with strings without a decimal point. Is there an alternative to that? Also the links you provided do not work anymore so I am using the https://docs.rs/nom/5.0.0-beta1/nom/number/complete/fn.float.html

Answer (score 9):

Just because nom heavily uses macros to do it's dirty work, don't forget that you can still apply normal programming best practices. Specifically, break down the problem into smaller parts and compose them.

In nom, this can be achieved with the `chain!` macro, which allows you to build up component parsers, and `named!`, to give them useful names.

I'd recommend creating sub-parsers for the three parts of the number - the optional sign, the required integral part, and the optional decimal part. Note that `digit` already pulls in multiple sequential numeric characters.

The main tricky thing with this code was the need to use `complete!` to force the `decimal` parser to be all-or-nothing.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;

use nom::digit;

named!(negative, tag!("-"));

named!(decimal, complete!(do_parse!(
    tag!(".")  >>
    val: digit >>
    (val)
)));

named!(floating_point<(Option<&[u8]>, &[u8], Option<&[u8]>)>, tuple!(
    opt!(negative), digit, opt!(decimal)
));

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", floating_point(&b"0"[..]));
    println!("{:?}", floating_point(&b"0."[..]));
    println!("{:?}", floating_point(&b"0.0"[..]));
    println!("{:?}", floating_point(&b"-0"[..]));
    println!("{:?}", floating_point(&b"-0."[..]));
    println!("{:?}", floating_point(&b"-0.0"[..]));
}
```

I've left off any conversion of the bytes to something interesting, it would clutter up the code and I don't really know how I'd do something useful with it anyway. ^_^

Comment: I believe this example needs to be updated. It currently fails to compile ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug)), and `chain!` [is deprecated since 2.0.0](http://rust.unhandledexpression.com/nom/macro.chain.html). I tried to modify this so it would compile, but haven't succeeded yet. Would you mind posting an update?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fiddling around and worked up an answer to my own question.

```
fn float_prs(input: &[u8]) -> nom::IResult<&[u8], f64> {
    let (i, name) = try_parse!(input,
                               recognize!(chain!(
                                   tag!("-")? ~
                                       take_while!(nom::is_digit) ~
                                       tag!(".")? ~
                                       take_while!(nom::is_digit)?,
                                   || {}
                               )));
    let num: &str = std::str::from_utf8(name).unwrap();
    nom::IResult::Done(i, num.parse::<f64>().unwrap())
}
```

Shepmaster's solution is also real good and has a distinct lack of `unwrap()` use. :)

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but this solution works with floating points and exponentials. The key is to ensure each sub-part of the number uses a `complete!` macro. This works with nom 3.2

```
named!(
    exponent,
    recognize!(complete!(preceded!(
        alt!(tag!("e") => { |_| b'e' } | tag!("E") => { |_| b'e'}),
        pair!(opt!(tag!("-")), many1!(digit))
    )))
);
named!(
    decimal,
    recognize!(complete!(terminated!(tag!("."), many0!(digit))))
);
named!(
    floating<f32>,
    map!(
        recognize!(do_parse!(
            opt!(tag!("-")) >> many1!(digit) >> opt!(decimal) >> opt!(exponent) >> (())
        )),
        |v| str::from_utf8(v).unwrap().parse::<f32>().unwrap()
    )
);

#[test]
fn parse_pdl_float_test() {
    assert_eq!(decimal(b".123").to_result(), Ok(".123".as_ref()));
    assert_eq!(floating(b"-123").to_result(), Ok(-123.0));
    assert_eq!(floating(b"123").to_result(), Ok(123.0));
    assert_eq!(floating(b"-123e4").to_result(), Ok(-123e4));
    assert_eq!(floating(b"123E4").to_result(), Ok(123e4));
    assert_eq!(floating(b"-123e-4").to_result(), Ok(-123e-4));
    assert_eq!(floating(b"-123.123e-4").to_result(), Ok(-123.123e-4));
}
```